# Why do mathematicians use $\Delta$ instead of $\nabla^2$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation

I often hear that, when writing PDEs, $\nabla^2$ is the convention among physicists and engineers, while mathematicians write $\Delta$ instead.

To me, the physicists' notation seems like it is objectively better: first you $\nabla$, then you $\nabla$ again.  Thus, $\nabla^2$.  Makes sense, right?

When mathematicians resist conventions from other disciplines, they generally have a good, concrete reason for doing so. So, what is the reason that mathematicians use $\Delta$?

Comment: Well, technically you're first applying $\nabla$ and then applying $\nabla \cdot$, which are different operators. I've also seen $\nabla ^k$ used to denote the $k$-th derivative (or collection of $k$-th order partial derivatives).

Comment: The reason is that $\nabla^2$ is a ridiculous abuse of notation. $\nabla$ means gradient so $\nabla^2$ should in fact be the Hessian (as written). The more correct notation would be $\nabla\cdot\nabla$. Moreover, the notation $\nabla^2$ can really lead you astray in curvilinear coordinates if you're not careful.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Would you elaborate on why $\nabla^2$ is a ridiculous abuse of notation in an answer?

Comment: As for why mathematicians don't use the notation $\nabla\cdot\nabla$ and instead use $\Delta$, I'm not exactly sure. However older texts in mathematics often used *words* instead of symbols for operators. I think through the middle of the twentieth century, this was still common practice. I recall seeing $\operatorname{div}(\operatorname{grad}f)$ in old papers and books. Mathematicians often do not use div or grad independently, but $\Delta$ is quite important so to de-emphasize div and grad, they may have chosen to use $\Delta$.

Comment: I like $\nabla^2$ better for functions!

Comment: The use of div and grad is not only restricted to "old" papers and books. For instance in the field of Continuum Mechanics, div and Div are used and have different meanings to boot!

Comment: I'm not sure mathematicians really resist notation from other disciplines as much as we tend to change our notation over time. In my experience, physics notation was also math notation... from the time in history when that physics was written... so, other disciplines sometimes have notational timecapsules. That said, notation varies.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f$ be a scalar field.

Then, $\nabla^2$  is the Hessian, i.e. the matrix $\nabla^2 f=\dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$ , while $\Delta$ is the Laplacian, i.e. the scalar $\Delta f=\Sigma_{i}\dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x_i^2 }$

Comment: You may want to put the RHS of your first equation in the usual form $(a_{ij})_{i,j}$ to emphasize that it gives you a matrix and avoid confusion.